# combine 2 queries from the same table into one linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I have 2 queries that are query the same table but with different parameters and I would like to combine into one ,
Query 1

```
 //ToDo refactor
        int myDayOfWeek = 0;
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;
        myDayOfWeek = (int)dt.DayOfWeek;

        var todaysLecture = (from c in _context.LectureGigs.Where(g => g.IsWeekLy == true && (int)g.Days == (myDayOfWeek))
                             select c).ToList();
        //results Ok 1 result
```

Query 2

```
var upCommingLecture = _context.LectureGigs
            .Include(g => g.Artist).Include(g => g.Genre)
            .Where(g => g.DateTime > DateTime.Now && !g.IsCanceled);
        //results Ok 2 result
```

The Query I would like to create

```
 var upCommingLecture = _context.LectureGigs
           .Include(g => g.Artist).Include(g => g.Genre).Where(g => g.IsWeekLy == true && (int)g.Days == (myDayOfWeek))
           .Where(g => g.DateTime > DateTime.Now && !g.IsCanceled);
        //Error none but 0 result
```

I have also tried this

```
var upCommingLecture = _context.LectureGigs
           .Include(g => g.Artist).Include(g => g.Genre)
           .Where(g => g.DateTime > DateTime.Now && !g.IsCanceled && g.IsWeekLy==true &&(int)g.Days==(myDayOfWeek));
        //Error none but 0 result
```

Comment: Can you not use the where clause to use an OR condition? that way you can have both your statements as one?

Comment: Hi, in my query I would like to get both results(q1 and q2 -3 items total) and not results of one  of the  queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*OR* (`||`), not *AND* (`&&`)

```
var upCommingLecture = _context.LectureGigs
       .Include(g => g.Artist).Include(g => g.Genre)
       .Where(g => (g.DateTime > DateTime.Now && !g.IsCanceled) 
                || (g.IsWeekLy==true &&(int)g.Days==(myDayOfWeek)));
```

Comment: OP: It's important to note the parentheses here.  Each side of the OR is wrapped in parens, because not doing that would have much different results, because WITHIN each side are AND operators.

Comment: the Or (||) is Not my Intent I need both results

Comment: @AssafOur in your comment above (to your original question) you said you wanted 3 items to be returned. That's what the OR here gives you. It will give you the items that that satisfy Query 1 (1 item) OR Query 2 (2 items), which means it will give you 1 item + 2 items = 3 items.